# Using a "local database" with a WPF DataGrid

Tags: .net, datagrid, local-database

I'm starting to make some test with .NET 4 / WPF. I made a local database with a table called "Fournisseurs".

Then I created a WPF form, with a DataGrid in it.

Then I wanted to bind my table to it. But I can't find how to make it.

I read some tutorials about binding DataSet to DataGrid but I can't find any guide showing how to create a DataSet from my local database...

Any ideas or tips please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look into [LINQ-to-Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx) to attach to your local database instance.  In doing so, you will get object representations of the data which you can then easily bind to the DataGrid.

Comment: I created an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" and mapped it to my Fournisseurs table. (I followed that guide http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/02/01/a-simple-example-of-using-linq-and-entity-framework.aspx ) and there is still nothing in my available bindings for my DataGrid :S Any ideas?